# How do I represent my 3-qubit state in the computational basis?

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I have taken the tensor product of $|0\rangle \otimes |-\rangle \otimes |+\rangle$ which resulted in the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1/2\\
1/2 \\
-1/2 \\
-1/2 \\
0 \\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

How would I represent this in the computational basis basis $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$?

Answer (score 2):

The elements of your vector are coefficients of the state in the computational basis

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2\\
1/2 \\
-1/2 \\
-1/2 \\
0 \\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
&\begin{matrix}
|000\rangle \\
|001\rangle \\
|010\rangle \\
|011\rangle \\
|100\rangle \\
|101\rangle \\
|110\rangle \\
|111\rangle
\end{matrix}
\end{array}
$$

so

$$
|0\rangle\otimes|-\rangle\otimes|+\rangle = \frac{|000\rangle + |001\rangle - |010\rangle - |011\rangle}{2}.
$$

We can confirm by direct calculation in Dirac notation

$$
\begin{align}
|0\rangle\otimes|-\rangle\otimes|+\rangle &= |0\rangle\otimes\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \otimes \frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \\
&= \frac{|0\rangle\otimes (|00\rangle + |01\rangle - |10\rangle - |11\rangle)}{2} \\
&= \frac{|000\rangle + |001\rangle - |010\rangle - |011\rangle}{2}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate the help